# Haskell - List pattern matching on multiple parameters? (cannot construct the infinite type)

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I'm having trouble using list pattern with multiple parameters. For example, trying to define:

```
somefunction (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:[y]
```

results in `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0]`.

Basically, I want to take two lists as parameters to a function and manipulate each of them using the (x:xs) pattern matching approach. Why is this wrong and how can I do it right? Thank you much!

**EDIT:** Update with more code as suggested was needed in answers.

```
somefunction a [] = [a]:[]
somefunction [] b = [b]:[]
somefunction (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:[y]
```

**EDIT 2:** Missed an important update. The error I'm getting with the above code is `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [[t0]]`. I think I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function snippet is perfectly sound:

```
(! 514)-> ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> let f (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:[y]
Prelude> :type f
f :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

But the context contradicts that type, and the type inference give you that error.  For instance, I can create a context that will give this error:

```
Prelude> let g xs ys = xs : ys
Prelude> :type g
g :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

And then if I combine `f` and `g` like below, then I get your error:

```
Prelude> let z x y = g x (f x y)

<interactive>:7:20:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    In the first argument of `f', namely `x'
    In the second argument of `g', namely `(f x y)'
    In the expression: g x (f x y)
Prelude>
```

To understand you error properly, you will need to examine (or post) enough context.

Comment: Ah, it does indeed! Updating with the code the additional code that causes the problem. I'll work on solving it myself from there, but I suppose getting the answer to my problem would certainly be nice as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with all 3 lines taken together:

```
somefunction a [] = [a]:[]
somefunction [] b = [b]:[]
somefunction (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:[y]
```

None of them are incorrect taken on their own. The problem is that the three equations are inconsistent about the return type of `somefunction`.

From the last equation, we can see that both arguments are lists (since you pattern match on them using the list constructor `:`).

From the last equation, we can see that the return type is a list whose elements must be the same type as the elements of the argument lists (which must also both be the same type), since the return value is `x:[y]` (which is more often written `[x, y]`; just the list containing only the two elements `x` and `y`) and `x` and `y` were elements of the argument lists. So if `x` has type `t0`, the arguments to `somefunction` both have type `[t0]` and the return type is `[t0]`.

Now try to apply those facts to the first equation. `a` must be a list. So `[a]` (the list containing exactly one element `a`) must be a *list of lists*. And then `[a]:[]` (the list whose first element is `[a]` and whose tail is empty - also written `[[a]]`) must be a *list of lists of lists*! If the parameter `a` has type `[t0]` (to match the type we figured out from looking at the last equation), then `[a]` has type `[[t0]]` and `[a]:[]` (or `[[a]]`) has type `[[[t0]]]`, which is the return type we get from this equation.

To reconcile what we learned from those two equations we need to find some type expression to use for `t0` such that `[t0] = [[[t0]]]`, which also requires that `t0 = [[t0]]`. This is impossible, which is what the error message `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [[t0]]` was about.

If your intention was to return one of the parameters as-is when the other one is empty, then you need something more like:

```
somefunction a [] = a
somefunction [] b = b
somefunction (x:xs) (y:ys) = [x, y]
```

Or it's possible that the first two equations were correct (you intend to return a list of lists of lists?), in which case the last one needs to be modified. Without knowing what you wanted the function to do, I can't say.

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to write:

```
somefunction xs [] = xs
somefunction [] ys = ys
somefunction (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : []
```

You have extra brackets. And your definition of `x : y` not contains `[]`. So compiler think, `y` is already a list